# Does the space $V = \{ v \in {H^1}(0,1),{v_x}(0) = {v_x}(1) = 0,\int\limits_0^1 {v = 0}\} $ make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Does this space make sense? 
$$V = \{ v \in {H^1}(0,1),{v_x}(0) = {v_x}(1) = 0,\int\limits_0^1 {v = 0}\}$$
where $H^1$ is the usual sobolev space.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You often see $H^1$ defined as the space of functions $f$ such that $f,f'\in L^2$. But that $f'$ is a "weak derivative"; in fact a function in $H^1$ need not be differentiable. So it doesn't really make sense to talk about $f'(0)$ for $f\in H^1$.

Of course whether the definition "makes sense" depends on exactly what you mean by the definition. You *could* define $V$ to be the space of all $f\in H^1$ such that $f'(0)$ and $f'(1)$ both *exist* and equal $0$.

That makes sense because elements of $H^1$ *are* continuous, hence they *do* have well-defined values at every point, so you *can* talk about whether they're differentiable at a point. This is in contrast to for example the space $L^1$; talking about the space of $f\in L^1$ such that $f(0)=0$ *really* makes *no* sense, because there's really no such thing as $f(0)$ in that case.

Comment: Thank you sir, I understand better now.

Comment: David C.Ultrich, I sutdied the existence of solution of some hyperbolic problem by using Faedo-Galerkoin method, and I found that $u$ and $u_t$ are in the spece above,  does this amplie that the solution dose not exist ?

Comment: @Gustav I have no idea whether this says anything about your solution to that problem; that would depend on the details of exactly what you did. You might try posting a more detailed question - you probably won't get any feedback from me, I don't know anything about PDEs.

Comment: C.Ultrish   I posted the full problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541084/faedo-galerkin-method-for-the-1-d-von-karman-system